# While doesn't work when i try to compare 2 int value (1 form user input, 1 from data .txt file) (student record project)

Tags: c

I tried to fix this problem for the evening to late at night but I still don't figure out where I'm wrong. The problem is about function search students. Even the user type in a correct Student's ID but it always sends back "No record" (else). I am so new to program C and tomorrow I have to submit this project. I will very much appreciate it if someone can help me. Thanks so much. here is the full code.
https://gist.github.com/KilveKlein/92cf95799ba99f86feccfa81b5bc9ed1

```
void search_student() {
     int find_student_id;
     printf("3. search student: \n\n\n");
     int student_ID = 0;
     int isFound = 0;
     printf("Type ID student: "); fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%u", &find_student_id);
     FILE *file;
     file = fopen("DataStudentRecord.txt", "rb");
     while (fread(&stu, sizeof(stu), 1, file)) {
         if (stu.ID == find_student_id) {
             isFound = 1;
             break;
         }
    }
    if (isFound) {
         printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tInfo student");
         printf("Name: %s", stu.fullName);
         printf("ID: %s", stu.ID);
         printf("class: %d", stu.classRoom);
         printf("Date of birth: %s", stu.dateOfBirth);
         printf("Gender: %s", stu.gender);
         printf("section: %s", stu.section);
         printf("address: %s", stu.address);
         printf("phone number: %ld", stu.phoneNumber);
    } else {
        printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tNo record.\n");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter to continue...");
        getch();
        system("cls");
   }
   fclose(file);
   return;
}
```

Comment: could you include your ```stu``` struct?

Comment: `scanf("%u", &find_student_id);` <<-- You are using "%u" to read a signed int. BTW: Why dont you just print all the records, including the outcome of the comparison?

Comment: are you certain ```fread()``` correctly reads the data into your struct?

Comment: Your `.txt` extension implies that the data is ascii text (e.g. you read a line with `fgets` and _parse_ it, filling in the `struct` fields). But, you're using `fread` to read binary data into the `struct`. So, which is it? Note that `fflush(stdin)` is UB (undefined behavior). I'd refactor the code to _not_ use it.

Comment: Please show a [mre] which demonstrates your observations.

Comment: You presumably intended to flush stdout?

Comment: The code at the link writes binary data, it is misleading to give it a .txt extension.

Comment: Use a debugger to see what is going on. What does a student ID look like?  What value are you entering.

Comment: yes im using struct

Comment: `struct student {
    char fullName[20];
    int ID;
    char classRoom[10];
    char gender[3];
    int dateOfBirth;
    char address[20];
    char section[20];
    int phoneNumber;
};

struct student stu;`

Comment: _Never_ use `gets` -- it is a huge security bug and the man page for it tells you to _not_ use it and _why_. Use `fgets` instead. And, don't combine `fgets` and `scanf` -- they tend to interfere with one another. Just use `fgets` throughout. Then, you _could_ do (e.g): `char buf[1000]; fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin); sscanf(buf,"%d",&myint);`

Comment: How do you create/write to "DataStudentRecord.txt"? Most probably that does not match the way how you read it. -- Insert some `printf()` in the `while` loop to see what is read. -- Oh, and don't forget to use `'\n'` at the end of each output line, as you did in the `isFound` case.